# What does "ongtray" mean?

Tags: meaning, agatha-christie, mysterious-mr-quin, harley-quin

In "The Bird with a Broken Wing," part of Agatha Christie's story collection, *The Mysterious Mr Quin*, Inspector Winkfield tells Mr Satterthwaite:

> Must find out what terms they were on. That’s where you can be useful to us, Mr Satterthwaite. You’ve the *ongtray* here, and you can get the hang of things in a way we can’t. Find out what relations there were between the two.

What does "ongtray" mean? Searches on Google mostly yield the same quoted text, with people complaining that searching didn't yield anything useful.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it means "entrée" but I am not entirely sure why Agatha Christie wrote *ongtray* instead. Checking the meaning of "entrée":

> 1. The main course of a meal.
>      1.1 *British* A dish served between the first and main courses at a formal dinner.
> 2. The right to enter or join a particular sphere or group.
>
> *- [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/entree)*

(2) fits the context.

Additionally, Google gives some other results for "ongtray" which match  "entrée":

- [*The Brass Bottle*, F. Anstey](http://wordincontext.com/en/ongtray):

  > "I was going to ask you, sir, before them parcels came," she began, with a dry cough of disapproval, "what you would like in the way of ongtray to-morrow night. I thought if I could find a sweetbread at all reasonable "

  Seems to fit (1).
- [*Bring Larks and Heroes*,
  Thomas Keneally, 2016](https://books.google.com/books/about/Bring_Larks_and_Heroes.html?id=eyTLDAAAQBAJ):

  > 'Ongtray!' called Mrs Blythe. 'She means go in,' Ann hissed at him.

  Maybe fits (2), but I suppose it's a bit of a stretch. Perhaps the same word but in French?
- And [*The Complete Servant* by Samuel and Sarah Adams, 1825](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Complete_Servant.html?id=xRIJAQAAMAAJ) has this entry in a glossary including French words:

  > *Entrée* (ong-tray) Entrance.

---

I suppose the use of "ongtray" here perhaps indicates some over-enunciation from the good Inspector.

Comment: This is similar to [eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect), except it's more mispronunciation than dialect. Without knowing anything about this character, I'd guess this might indicate he's not very "cultured" (e.g. doesn't speak French well), but possibly likes to pretend to be (by dropping French words anyway). Cf. “Parlay voo Frongsay?” in *The Railway Children* (in that context, spoken by a child, so not the same sort of cultural indications).

Comment: *Le franglais est un doddle*, except for those who don't remember that French was the language of international communication and diplomacy in the 19th and early 20th century ;-)

Comment: More on eye dialect [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137922/is-there-a-special-word-for-purposely-misspelling-a-word).

Comment: In the Keneally, it esems to be for *Entrez!*, not for *entrée*.